# Negate regex subexpression

Tags: regex, linux

If I have a pattern such as `(word1|word2|word3)` how do I specify in a regex anything not matching these subexpression? I.e. how do I negate this?

Comment: Using lookarounds. But do you really want regex?

Comment: Depending on how you plan to use that regex, you might just change the operation. E.g., in Python `re.split(regex, string)` is the same as `re.findall(negated_regex, string)`

Comment: @MarounMaroun:Trying to use sed...

Answer (score 2):

Try adding (?!pattern). This should negate the whole pattern.